# ComboBox in codename one

Tags: codenameone

How to highlight the selected item in ComboBox using codename one?

I created a combo box object and added some list of objects to it and added the ComboBox to the form.Whenever the application runs it shows a combo box with the items,but my objective is to highlight the selected item in ComboBox.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a cell renderer and replace the combo box renderer to present the information in the way you want. See the [developer guide's components](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/components.html) section for a more thorough discussion of renderers.